# Synonyms for two apps

Tags: macos, alfred

I want to remove the Evernote application from my computer, but I have built up a lot of muscle memory for opening Evernote using Alfred.

Is there a way I can create a "synonym" in Alfred so if I type in "Evernote", Alternote will be in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an Automator app that simply opens up Alternote, but naming it Evernote might be the best approach.

---

**UPDATE:** Sadly, the symlink approach won't work. http://support.alfredapp.com/kb:symlinked-apps

Creating a symlink might be a good solution.

```
ln -s /Applications/Alternote.app Evernote
```